# Maximum number of characters on Results to Text not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I don't know why SQL Server Management Studio keeps with the 256 default limit limit even after I setup to 3,000. I closed it and opened again, restarted the computer (maybe it would be a stupid cache, you never know.. ) but still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[image: management studio screen]

Comment: which sql server version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I found that just creating a new query window applies the new limit.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in sql server 2008 and its working properly.
http://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/tips-for-querying-text-columns-in-ssms/